# Getting Required fields

Tags: apex, required

I would like to get required fields for an object selected on a VF page , how can this be achieved. I have the describe call, but the object input will need to be dynamically fed from the VF page selected object from drop down..

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = sobjectfromVFPAGE.sObjectType.getDescribe();

Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> M = r.fields.getMap();

for(String fieldName : M.keySet()) { 
    Schema.SObjectField field = M.get(fieldName);
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = field.getDescribe();
    //A nillable field can have empty content. A isNillable Boolean non-nillable
    // field must have a value for the object to be
    // created or saved. 
    // if F.isNillable() is false then field is mandatory
    Boolean isFieldreq  = F.isNillable() ;
    System.debug ('F = ' + fieldName + ' isnul= ' +  isFieldreq);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) method to make it dynamic. Quoting from documentation:

> Returns a map of all sObject names (keys) to sObject tokens (values)
>   for the standard and custom objects defined in your organization.

Assuming this property- `sobjectfromVFPAGE` returns Object API Name, here is the required snippet:

```
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> M = 
    Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjectfromVFPAGE).fields.getMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple flaws in your premise:

1. A field is required if its describe returns a value of `false` when calling the `isNillable()` method.
2. A field can be made required in ways that are not reflected via describes, most notably through `Validation Rules`.

Consider, for example, this simple rule on the `Opportunity` object:

```
ISBLANK(Description)
```

Writing a rule such as the above will in essence make `Description` a required field. However, your schema based approach will entirely miss it because this mechanic doesn't show up in the schema.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code. Please see the changes marked as bold : -

```
**String str = 'Address__c';
Map <String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType sobjType = gd.get(str);
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = sobjType.getDescribe();**
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = r.fields.getMap();
System.debug('------'+M);

for(String fieldName : M.keySet()) {
    Schema.SObjectField field = M.get(fieldName);
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = field.getDescribe();
    Boolean isFieldreq  = F.isNillable() ;
    System.debug ('F = ' + fieldName + ' isnul= ' +  isFieldreq);
}
```

i think it will solve your purpose.